terraform GCP cloud functions cloud build docker_repository configuration throws error about format but format is right
When I deploy a cloud function v2 using terraform trying to specify a docker_repository, I get this error

Error: Error creating function: googleapi: Error 400: Repository name projects/org-service-accounts-401323/locations/us/repositories/gcr.io has an invalid format. It should match the pattern projects/{project}/locations/{location}/repositories/{repository}.

But the format looks correct....
Using terraform 1.9.5 and google provider 5.42.0
Here are the configs I tried
build_config {
    runtime = "nodejs18"
    entry_point = "onRequest" # Set the entry point
    # docker_repository = "us-east1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/my-repo/my-image"
    docker_repository =         "projects/${var.common_project_id}/locations/us/repositories/${var.registry_name}"
    # docker_repository = "${var.common_project_id}/us/${var.registry_name}"
 
    source {
    storage_source {
    bucket = google_storage_bucket.default.name
    object = google_storage_bucket_object.default.name
    }
}

I tried the various formats of repository id strings above but nothing worked, I kept getting the 400 error

I encountered something similar recently. My understanding is that this is a consequence of Google migrating Container Registry (us.gcr.io/{repo}/{image}) repos to Arfitact Registry (e.g. {location}-docker.pkg.dev/{project}/{repo}/{image}). IIUC your image is in a (former?) Container Registry repo and I think (!) you need to (continue to) reference it as us.gcr.io/${var.registry_name}/{image}:{tag}
